# i want to check the the given value present in a dataset column or not

Tags: c#, dataset

I want to check the given value present in a dataset column. 
I was insert the value using separator and stored in a column name fld empname.
Example the dataset field fldempname have the value Hari,vinoth,Arun. suppose i ll insert again the value hari and arun means it display error message Like this Employee name already present otherwise the value inserted.
please help me..

My partial code is here..

```
 for (int i = 0; i < lstbox.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (lstbox.Items[i].Selected)
                        {
                            string id = lstbox.Items[i].Text;
                            DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getallattendancesetupTableAdapter TA1 = new DataSet4TableAdapters.sp_getallattendancesetupTableAdapter();
                            DataSet4.sp_getallattendancesetupDataTable DS1 = TA1.GetData();
                            if (DS1.Rows.Count == 0)
                            {
                                employee = employee + lstbox.Items[i].Text + ",";
                            }
                            else if (DS1.Rows.Count > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (DataRow dr in DS1.Rows)
                                {
                                    foreach (string category in dr["fldemployee"].ToString().Split(','))
                                    {
                                        if (category != "")
                                        {
                                            if (category == id)
                                            {
                                                Value = Value + lstbox.Items[i].Text + "\\n";
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        continue;

                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with datasets in a while.. so there prob is cleaner/better way to do this..

```
 DataSet st = new DataSet();
 foreach (DataRow row in st.Tables["table_name"].Rows)
 {
      if (row["column_name"] == "value")
      {
         //found
      }
 }
```

*side note: i'd try Mitch Wheat's answer*

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx)'s [`Select()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method:

```
DataRow[] foundRows; 
foundRows = dataSet1.Tables["MyTable"].Select("fldempname = 'Hari'");
```

Comment: I have an another doubt i was insert the no of employee name in a column with separator ',' how can i check whether the given employee name is stored or not.

Comment: why did you originally accept this correct answer, and then change your mind? The other poster actally says use this method!